# Is there a difference between the 'degree' and 'dimension' of a matrix representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory, terminology

In *The Symmetric Group* the author, Bruce Sagan, uses the terms *degree* and *dimension* of a matrix representation synonymously to mean the number of columns of the matrices. However, I have also seen elsewhere that the degree has been defined as the number of columns in the matrices, whereas dimension refers to the dimension of the vector space on which the group acts. I guess the author can define the terms how he wants, but is there a convention for what these terms mean more precisely?

Comment: The representation is a homomorphism to $GL(V)$, with $\dim (V)=d$ as a vector space. This $d$ is also called the degree and we have $GL(V)\cong GL_d(K)$, where $V$ is a $K$-vector space.